# React native cannot read index.android.delta

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have already tried a lot but could not get it fix. Everything was working good before I added react-native-easy-gridview in my packages.json and then I checked out my changes after that I got this.
[image]

Here is my build.gradle

```
    apply plugin: "com.android.application"
import com.android.build.OutputFile


apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"


def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false


def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.pilbara_weed_management_mobile"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 8
        versionName "1.0"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
            release {
                if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
                    storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
                    storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
                    keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
                    keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
                }
            }
        }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':react-native-mauron85-background-geolocation')
    compile project(':react-native-background-task')
    compile project(':react-native-keep-awake')
    compile project(':react-native-background-timer')
    compile project(':react-native-image-resizer')
    compile project(':react-native-fcm')
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1' //this decides your firebase SDK version
    compile project(':react-native-fetch-blob')
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
    compile ("com.facebook.react:react-native:0.47.2") { force = true }  // From node_modules
    compile project(':react-native-smart-splashscreen')
    compile project(':react-native-fs')
    compile project(':react-native-file-opener')
    compile project(':react-native-camera')
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: I have started receiving same and that to from today only!

Comment: were you able to find any solution

Comment: solution is at https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/19259

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Edit android/app/build.gradle

use this

compile ("com.facebook.react:react-native:0.44.0") { force = true }

and write version of app you use instead of 0.44.0 and delete something like this
 compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"
or this
compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:0.44.0"

Comment: Thanks @mialnika. I did not work let me add something more in question.

Comment: could you provide me how your build.gradle looks like?

Comment: I removed my modules and cleared cache it worked after your solution thanks

Comment: I'm new to react native can you little explain why I needed to do that while it was working before.

Comment: This works! But it still looks like a workaround. It could bite you back when you upgrade RN version, forgetting to change this value also. Could potentially waste some hours (:

Answer (score 0):

It cause this error for the RN 0.60. You can solve this by following,

```
npm i jetifier
npx jetify
```

fixed it for me on RN 0.60.