# metro bundler error: ::ffff:127.0.0.1 - - [DATE] "GET <class-module-name" HTTP/1.1" 404 208 "-" "okhttp/3.12.1"

Tags: react-native, metro-bundler

#### Update:

- I have found a workaround. One of the (many) packages that I am using in the app is react-native-device-info. If I don't call it from within the app, the problem is gone (even if the app is still included in the build)
- When I tried to get the app's version number by accessing Platform.constants.Release, the problem occurs again.

#### The question: long story... I will try to make it short:

- My react-native app was running with RN 0.59.9
- I have upgraded RN to 0.62.2, and it is running with this version, too
- The app on android, however, became much slower
- I have two ways to try and resolve this: go back to RN 0.59.9, or use Hermes in 0.62.2
- The hermes build fails (different story), so I checked out the branch that worked with 0.59.9 and copied over the new application files from 0.62.2
- I got some errors indicating that application files are using packages that are not in my build (added after upgrading to 0.62.2), fixed them
- Now I am getting the following error in metro bundler:

**::ffff:127.0.0.1 - - [18/Oct/2020:09:21:04 +0000] "GET <class-module-name"> <HTTP/1.1" 404 208 "-" "okhttp/3.12.1"**

- I am getting it for the App.js file that is referenced from index.js, and for the first module that is imported in App.js. **The strange thing is that the bundler reported errors for these modules, so it accessed them already...**
- Any idea?

(I have read all the relevant github and stack overflow issues/questions mentioning a similar error. None solved my problem).

Answer (score 2):

Since you have upgraded RN, and then downgraded back, and then copied over files from different versions/branches, I would strongly recommend you to clear the cache when compiling:

To clear your cache:

react-native start --reset-cache

If you are using expo-cli, then use:

expo start -c

Comment: did you try (Edit android/app/build.gradle) ?  : 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50344830/react-native-cannot-read-index-android-delta

Comment: If I were you I will do the following (it usually works):

1. Use a new computer, 2. Install React Native and all the required modules, 3. Put the source codes back and try compiling the app again